# MVC filter not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am absolutely stumped on this one and was hoping someone here could help me.  I followed the example set out here

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

and I swear I had filtering working fine but then I came back to it to find that it no longer works.  When I run the page and I enter something in the filter and press "Search", I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /HomeController/Transactions

I have the following method in my HomeController.cs.

```
    public ActionResult Transactions(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "Date_Desc" : "Date";
        ViewBag.AmountSortParm = sortOrder == "Amount" ? "Amount_Desc" : "Amount";
        ViewBag.DescriptionSortParm = sortOrder == "Desc" ? "Desc_Desc" : "Desc";
        ViewBag.TableNameSortParm = sortOrder == "TableName" ? "TableName_Desc" : "TableName";
        ViewBag.CatTypeSortParm = sortOrder == "CatType" ? "CatType_Desc" : "CatType";
        ViewBag.CatNameSortParm = sortOrder == "CatName" ? "CatName_Desc" : "CatName";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var transactions = from s in db.Transactions
                       select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            transactions = transactions.Where(s => s.TranDescription.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.Account.Description.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.Category.CategoryType.CatType.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.Category.CatName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Date":
                transactions = transactions.OrderBy(s => s.TranDate);
                break;
            case "Date_Desc":
                transactions = transactions.OrderByDescending(s => s.TranDate);
                break;
            case "Amount":
                transactions = transactions.OrderBy(s => s.TranAmount);
                break;
            case "Amount_Desc":
                transactions = transactions.OrderByDescending(s => s.TranAmount);
                break;
            case "Desc":
                transactions = transactions.OrderBy(s => s.TranDescription);
                break;
            case "Desc_Desc":
                transactions = transactions.OrderByDescending(s => s.TranDescription);
                break;
            case "TableName":
                transactions = transactions.OrderBy(s => s.Account.Description);
                break;
            case "TableName_Desc":
                transactions = transactions.OrderByDescending(s => s.Account.Description);
                break;
            case "CatType":
                transactions = transactions.OrderBy(s => s.Category.CategoryType.CatType);
                break;
            case "CatType_Desc":
                transactions = transactions.OrderByDescending(s => s.Category.CategoryType.CatType);
                break;
            case "CatName":
                transactions = transactions.OrderBy(s => s.Category.CatName);
                break;
            case "CatName_Desc":
                transactions = transactions.OrderByDescending(s => s.Category.CatName);
                break;
            default:
                transactions = transactions.OrderByDescending(s => s.Account.Description);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(transactions.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

And I have the following code in my view (Transactions.cshtml).

```html
@model PagedList.IPagedList<finance.Models.Transaction>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Transactions";
}

<h2>Transactions</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Transactions", "HomeController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Date", "Transactions", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Amount", "Transactions", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.AmountSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Description", "Transactions", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DescriptionSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Account", "Transactions", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.TableNameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Main Category", "Transactions", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.CatTypeSortParm })
        </th> 
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Sub-Category", "Transactions", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.CatNameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TranDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TranAmount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TranDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Account.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryType.CatType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CatName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Add Category", "EditTransactions", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Transactions", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

This is the debug info from my trace.axd if it helps

```
PATH_INFO   /HomeController/Transactions

PATH_TRANSLATED D:\business\personal\finance\database\web\finance\finance\HomeController\Transactions

QUERY_STRING    SearchString=test

REMOTE_ADDR ::1

REMOTE_HOST ::1

REMOTE_PORT 65446

REQUEST_METHOD  GET

SCRIPT_NAME /HomeController/Transactions

SERVER_NAME localhost

SERVER_PORT 60085

SERVER_PORT_SECURE  0

SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1

SERVER_SOFTWARE Microsoft-IIS/8.0

URL /HomeController/Transactions

HTTP_CONNECTION keep-alive

HTTP_ACCEPT text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip, deflate

HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    en-US,en;q=0.5

ASP.NET_SessionId=mjhmmkoroa3f054opatmm4yn

HTTP_HOST   localhost:60085

HTTP_REFERER    http://localhost:60085/Home/Transactions

HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
```

Answer (score 0):

A 404 Error does not have to do with the Search. It has to do with routing.

try `/Home/Transactions`
or `/Transactions`

Even if you did not have the query parameters it would still hit the method.

Answer (score 0):

Since your action signature looks like `public ActionResult Transactions(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)` with only `page` being optional, you are missing parameters when sending form with:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Transactions", "HomeController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
       Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
       <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
}
```

You should add missing fields:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Transactions", "HomeController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
       Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
       @Html.TextBox("SortOrder")
       @Html.TextBox("CurrentFilter")
       <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that the url says

```
/HomeController/Transactions
```

It has to be

```
/Home/Transactions
```

so this is how you need to create the form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Transactions", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as     string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
```

You have

```
Html.BeginForm("Transactions", "HomeController", FormMethod.Get)
```

but is

```
Html.BeginForm("Transactions", "Home", FormMethod.Get)
```

MVC will resolve HomeController for you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492692(v=vs.118).aspx

Check out the example.